# Recurrence relation for basic operation

Tags: math, recursion, recurrence

I need a little help with creating a recurrence relation for the Basic Operation for the following recursive algorithm:

```
int D(int n) {
  if (n==0) {
    return 0;
  }
  return D(n - 1) + D(n - 1);
}
```

I think the basic operation for this is addition but I am having trouble setting up the recurrence relation

Comment: I think you probably misspecified this.  As given, it's a potentially very expensive way (O(2**n)) of handing you the value 0 for any positive argument `n`.

Comment: @pjs Yes I understand that this may be an expensive way but I was wondering what the recurrence relation for this algorithm's basic operation was, I think the recursive relation for this algorithm's computed value is 2 * D(n-1)

Comment: `T(n) = 2 * T(n-1) + c`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure this is the correct code?  The recurrence relation is

```
D(n) = 2 * D(n-1)
base case D(n) = 0
```

Do you see how this works?  The function's recursion step shows you the recurrence step; the function's termination clause shows you the base case.

I'm worried because in closed form, this is

```
D(n) = 0 for all n
```

Comment: yes, this is the correct code, I see how it is 2 * D(n-1) but is this for the basic operation or for the algorithm's computed value?

Comment: Both, I believe.  I'm not certain what "basic operation" might mean in your paradigm.

Comment: Basic operation is defined as the operation that takes the algorithm the longest time to compute in this case I assumed it was addition. For example, if you were to take the recursive algorithms for factorials: `if n = 0 return 1
else return F(n − 1) ∗ n` The recursive relation for the computed value is F(n) = F(n − 1)*n for n > 0, however the recursive relation for the basic operation(which is multiplication) is M(n) =M(n − 1) + 1 --> M(n-1) to compute F(n-1) and +1 to multiply F(n-1) with n

Comment: Yes, addition is the basic operation. Thanks.